# Can't connect to mysql database while setting up the wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am going to set up the wordpress.
But I couldn't access to the database systems while setting up wordpress.
Mysql server is installed correctly and I can access with username and password in MySQL Workbench and by using console command(mysql -u root -p) both.
I also create schema named "wordpress".
But can't connect on wordpress.
What is the issue?
Please help me.
Here I attached some images.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't use `root` to access your database from WordPress. Create a different user and give it only the access rights it need for the WordPress schema, and use that in your `wp-config.php file`

Comment: I think create a different user didn't work.
I create another user in workbench and tried to use that user but it didn't work.
And 'mysql -u root -p' command works well on the console.
I think it is not a problem also.

Comment: Also I have one more question.
I used "root" for username and "password" for password for connection in workbench.
After connect to the database system, I create another user named branch.
And I gave all the permission to that user.
What username do I have to use? "branch" or "root"?

Answer (score 0):

To update your database credentials in WordPress, follow these steps:

1. Copy the content of wp-config-sample.php.
2. Create a new file named wp-config.php.
3. Paste the copied content into the new file.
4. Update the database credentials in wp-config.php.

This should resolve the issue and your updated credentials will work 100%.

Comment: Actually, password is my database password.

Comment: I have updated my answer please try with that solution, Thanks!